# Notepad++ `Find in Files` displays all results except a certain keyword

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using notepad++ to search for certain keywords (using regular expression). something like (word1|word2|this statement|another statement). It works but can I search and show all results except a certain keyword? something like exclude the following words (exclude this|exclude this)? For example, below.

samedir\File1.log

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
exclude this
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
not excluded
excluding this
```

samedir\File2.log

```
This is line 1 1
This is line 2 1
This is line 3 1
exclude this
This is line 4 1
This is line 5 1 1
This is line 6 1
not excluded
excluding this
```

For example: I want to start a find in both files (on the same directory) but exclude the lines with `excluding this` and `exclude this`
the results should show something like below

File1.log

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
not excluded
```

File2.log

```
This is line 1 1
This is line 2 1
This is line 3 1
This is line 4 1
This is line 5 1 1
This is line 6 1
not excluded
```

Comment: a much cleaner example would be better.

Comment: What does "all results" mean? Every character in every file except something? Please elaborate.

Comment: I am not clear on what your asking. Provide some examples.

Comment: added more info on what I am trying to get into.

Comment: @jun What would be the output if the input is `foo bar exclude this` ?

Comment: The line containing `foo bar exclude this` will not show in the output because I asked to exclude `exclude this` in the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the regex like below to match all the lines which don't have `exclude` or `excluding this` strings.

```
^(?!.*\bexclud(?:ing|e) this\b).+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jU7iM0/2)

This `(?!.*\bexclud(?:ing|e) this\b)` negative lookahead at the start asserts that there isn't a string `exclude this` or `excluding this` present on the the line in which we are going to match. That is , the above regex would match all the lines except the one which contains `exclude this` or `excluding this`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a lookahead assertion:

`^(?!excluding this|exclude this)[^\r\n]*$`

This will match entire lines as long as they don't contain `excluding this` or `exclude this`.

The key is the `(?!)` part. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more info.

Comment: This did not work for me. Showed all the lines from the files. But really helpful on the link. Thanks though.

Comment: Please try it again. This should work. Just verified with Notepad++. http://oi62.tinypic.com/14tpnhe.jpg

Comment: still did not work for me. But this helped me a lot though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to exclude one string and search for two strings in one line, so I used this regex:

```txt
^(?!.*excludethisstring).*includethisstring1.*includethisstring2.*$
```

This will make it so that the one line searched MUST have the two strings included, if you want to search for either one of the lines:

```txt
^(?!.*excludethisstring).*(includethisstring1|includethisstring2).*$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be great if you give a congret example, too. (Text in the editor, regex, expected output)